# Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall b\in B ~ \exists a_n$ where $a_n \in A$ and $a_n\to b$ as $n\to\infty$. Prove $\sup(B)\leq \sup(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Question: Let A and B be two non-emty bounded sub-sets of $\mathbb{R}$
>   with the following proposition: $\forall_{b\in B}\exists_{(a_n)}$.
>   $(a_n)$ is made up of elements of A such that $a_n\to b$ as
>   $n\to\infty$

I don't know what to do with the sequence part.

> To be proven: $\sup(B)\leq \sup(A)$.

My attempt:

Suppose $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Then $a\leq sup(A)$ and $b\leq sup(B)$

If $b<a$ then $b\leq \sup(B)\leq a\leq \sup(A)$

Suppose $\sup(B)>\sup(A)$.

Then $\exists_{a\in A}$ such that $a>\sup(A)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

And $\exists_{b\in B}$ such that $b>\sup(B)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

But if $\sup(B)>\sup(A)$, then $b>a$. But $b<a$. So contradiction. So $\sup(B)\leq \sup(A)$.

Hope someone will take a look, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint:  Let $t>\sup A$.  Show that it follows that  $t \geq \sup B $.  Therefore ...

Comment: What is $t$? And if $t\in A$, then $t\leq \sup A$?

Comment: Take *any* number   $t$ that is larger than $\sup A$.  Then show that  $t\geq\sup B$.  This is a standard way to prove an inequality.   Suppose  I want to show that $X\leq Y $.  I  can  do this by showing that $X$ is less than any number  larger  than  $Y$.

Comment: You have successfully proved [in the post you deleted] that if $t$ is any number larger than $\sup A$ it is true that $\sup B \leq t$.  Therefore  $\sup B \leq \sup A$.  QED.  [Tidy the exposition a bit.  "Suppose that $b$ is an arbitrary element of $B$.  Then there is a sequence $a_n\to b$ of elements of $A$.  Since each $a_n<t$ it follows that $b\leq t$.  As this holds for all elements $b$ of $B$ it follows now that $\sup B \leq t$.  Finally, this is true for any $t$ greater than $\sup A$ and consequently $\sup B \leq \sup A$."

Comment: Got a bit confused at the end:  if $t>\sup A$, then how can $\sup B \leq t$ lead to $\sup B \leq \sup A$ if $t$ is never equal to $\sup A$?

Comment: This needs to be obvious to you, so work on it.  It is so frequently used in analysis that any time spent now will be well worth it.  Consider it this way:  I am thinking of a number, say $x$.  About that number I can promise you only this fact.  If you choose *any* number $t$ that is strictly larger than $10$ then I promise you that $x<t$.  No other information.  Can you tell me anything at all about my number $x$?  [Note the *any* number--you are forgetting that in your confusion here.]

Comment: Then I will definitely spend some time on that!! It's just that notices that there is a possibility that $t=\sup B$ (because $\sup B\leq t$), so then $\sup A<\sup B$. So then it would be more logic, to me, to say that $\sup A\leq\sup B$. But I think that I shouldn't think that way, as $\sup B \leq t$ doesn't necessarily imply that it has to be equal at some point. But so if $x\leq t$ and $y<t$, then $x\leq y$?

Comment: Would you like to check another proof of mine maybe? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598667/real-analysis-supremum-proof 
And thank you for your help!

Comment: You are trying to deduce something from *one* value of $t$.  What you need to think about is that you have infinitely many $t$ available, especially those values of $t$ that are only a small bit larger than $\sup A$.

Comment: I will keep that in mind! How did you even come up with the idea? Do you have some good literature on real-analysis?

Comment: Good perhaps?  Free though:  http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf

Comment: Thanks, will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence part tells you that every point of $B$ is an adherent point of $A$. Thus $B\subset \overline{A}$. where $\overline A$ stands for the closure 
of $A$ in $\mathbb R$, i.e. the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb R$ containing $A$.

$B\subset \overline A\Rightarrow \overline B\subset \overline{\overline A}$
 but $\overline{\overline A}=\overline {A}$. Hence,

$\overline B\subset \overline A$

And,

$\overline B\subset \overline A\Rightarrow \sup(B)\leq \sup(A)$.

since:

(1) $\sup(X)$ is an increasing function of subset $X\subset E$ of an ordered set $E$.
$\overline B\subset \overline A\Rightarrow \sup(\overline B)\leq \sup(\overline A)$.

(2) $\overline A$ is closed and bounded (since $A$ is bounded)  (then compact) having $\sup(\overline A)=\max(\overline A)=\sup(A)$, idem for $\overline B$.

Comment: A minor misstatement:  "The sequence part tells you that every point of $B$ is *either also in $A$ or else* an accumulation point of $A$."

Comment: If $B$ and $A$ contain exactly one point I don't think I would be inclined to talk about "accumulation points."  Maybe your text does.  Me, I would edit your statement that "An accumulation point of $A$ is the limit of a convergent sequence" to read instead "An accumulation point of $A$ is the limit of a convergent sequence *of distinct points* of $A$".

Comment: Due to the ambiguous status of the notion of accumulation point, I will replace it for what it was meant here: an adherent point of set $A$. Explictely: a point $x\in \mathbb R$ such that every open set containing $x$ intersects $A$. Every point of $A$ is adherent to $A$, i.e. $A\subset \overline A$. If $A$ is $\{a\}$ its closure (or adherence) = $\overline A=\{a\}$. Consider the stationary sequence $a_n=a\ \forall n\in \mathbb N$. Thanks for comments.

Comment: The Source Of All Supreme Knowledge (i..e., Wiki) agrees with your switch to using "adherent point" in place of "accumulation point."    Defy the Wiki Gods at your peril.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your proof is not right. You need to use the assumption given in the problem. Let's have a look at your proof. You write:

> Suppose $a∈A$ and $b∈B$.
>
> Then $a≤\sup(A)$ and $b≤\sup(B)$
>
> If $b<a$ then $b≤\sup(B)≤a≤\sup(A)$

Your conclusion that $b\leq a$ doesn't follow from what you write. You only have that $b<a$, and $b\leq\sup(B)$, which does not imply $\sup(B)\leq a$.

You write:

> Suppose sup(B)>sup(A).
>
> Then ∃a∈A such that $a>\sup(A)−\frac ϵ2$.
>
> And ∃b∈B such that $b>\sup(B)−\frac ϵ2$.
>
> But if sup(B)>sup(A), then $b>a$. But $b<a$. So
> contradiction.

I don't know how you obtained a contradiction here. You conclude that $b>a$, but that this contradicts $b<a$, which seem to come out of nowhere.

I would do it as follows: Let $x = \sup(B)$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Take $b\in B$, such that $b > x-\frac\epsilon 2$, and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of elements from $A$, such that $a_n\to b$. Then the sequence $a_n$ comes within $\frac\epsilon 2$ of $b$ from some point on, meaning that it comes within $\epsilon$ of $x$ from some point on. Use this to argue that $\sup(A)\geq x$.

Comment: I don't think i got it, why does the sequence $a_n$ come within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ of b from some point on?

Comment: @DeLorean it is because the sequence $a_n$ converges to $b$. When a sequence converges to a number, than sequence becomes arbitrarily close to that number. In particular, the sequence is within a distance of $\frac\epsilon 2$ from $b$ from some point and onwards, i.e. there exists an $N$, such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-b|<\frac\epsilon 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple:

Assume that $\beta:=\sup B>\sup A=:\alpha$. Then $\mu:={\alpha+\beta\over2}$ satisfies $\beta>\mu>\alpha$. By definition of $\beta$ there is a $b\in B$ with $b>\mu$, and by the special assumption in the question there is an $a\in A$ with $a>\mu$ as well – contradicting the definition of $\alpha$.