# Real analysis supremum proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A$ be a non-empty bounded sub-set of $\mathbb{R}$. Let
>   $B\subset\mathbb{R}$, given by $$B=\left\{\frac{a_1+2a_2}{2} \,\Bigg|\,a_1,a_2\in
>  A\right\}$$ Express $\sup B$ in terms of $\sup A$.

My attempt:
Suppose $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Then $a_1 \leq \sup (A)$ and $a_2\leq \sup (A)$

So $a_1 + 2a_2\leq 3sup (A)$.

This gives $\frac{a_1 + 2a_2}{2}\leq \frac{3\sup (A)}{2}$.

This means that $\frac{3\sup (A)}{2}$ is an upperbound and $\sup(B)\leq\frac{3\sup (A)}{2}$.

Now let $\epsilon>0$.

$a_1>\sup(A) - \frac{2\epsilon}{3}$

$a_2>\sup(A) - \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

This gives $\frac{a_1 + 2a_2}{2}> \frac{3\sup (A)}{2}-\epsilon$.

So this means that $\frac{3\sup(A)}{2}\leq\sup(B)$

So $\sup(B)=\frac{3\sup(A)}{2}$.

Is this correct? And how can I improve my proofs?

Comment: Ideas are good, write-up ... not so much.  You start off "Suppose ... $b\in B$."  Who is this lonely boy $b$ who plays no role in the proof and is never mentioned again.  What is he doing at this party?  Who invited him?

Comment: So I can basically leave him at home?

Comment: No.  I'd prefer he justify his presence.  Start off "Let $b$ be an arbitrary point of the set $B$.  Then, by definition, there exist points $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $A$  so that $b=\frac12 a_1 +a_2$."  Now $b$ has two friends at the party rather than  two random guys who have no idea what they are supposed to do for $b$.

Comment: Of course!! Thanks, you helped me a lot today!!

Answer (score 0):

There are Lemmas that would be helpful.

$\sup(A+B) = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

$\sup(cA) = c\sup(A), c\geq 0$

where A, B are subset of R, $A + B = \{z = a + b| a \in A, b \in B\}$, and c is a non-negative real number

then your questions can be answered: $\sup((A + 2*A)/2) = 3\sup(A)/2$

Comment: You probably mean $c \ge 0$.

Comment: @mechanodroid yes, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct.

You can also do this: let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence in $A$ such that $a_n \to \sup A$. Then $$B \ni \frac{a_n + 2a_n}2 \to \frac{\sup A + 2\sup A}2 = \frac32 \sup A$$ so $\sup B \ge \frac32 \sup A$.